# How to horizontally align tabs in chrome-dev-menu,instead of vertical alignment, for extension React-dev tools?

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome-devtools, react-devtools

I am building ReactApp, and for debugging using React-Dev-Tools,

while testing states of the component, It shows two menus side by side,at left side `<React/> code` and at right values of states.

[image: screenshot]

debugging screen is divided vertically between two.

but, I am following a tutorial, where these menus are horizontally divided and seem efficient and more readable compared to mine.

tutor's screen = more readable code, due to horizontal alignment.

[image: screenshot2]

but my screen-space is wasted due to a vertical division as this,

[image: screenshot3]

I also tried dock(debugger menu) at the bottom, but it's more readable.[image: screenshot4]

How can I align two menus/tabs horizontally in chrome tools, though I had reset settings in debug menu?

Edit 1: after getting solution.

after increasing font size, the screen is not splitting vertically, and I am getting same chrome-dev-tools-screen, as same as that of my tutor.

[image: screenshot5]

Comment: TLDR; `ctrl ++`, to get vertical split, also, first click in debug screen then increase the size of the screen by `ctrl ++`, not increasing the size of browsing window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The vertical split happens when you reduce the dev-tools window size.
This feature is described on this github page:
https://github.com/facebook/react-devtools/pull/541

Here is the video showing it:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RdKVJEy41M4

Comment: thank you for explaining this, I checked when screen width is below 965px, it's splitting screen vertically. but when I changed zoom level by `CTRL + `, it is not splitting at 965px. I also added a screenshot of resultant-screen.

Answer (score 1):

You can split tabs horizontally in Chrome 87 (and see one of them). Right click Network in the menu and select "Move to bottom"

[image: Move any Tab Under other tabs]